# Is it possible in Android to implement Zoomable scroll view with both the scrollbars visible in the viewport?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, scrollview, zooming

I am trying to develop a zoomable scrollview with seeing both the scrollbars visible. But when implementing I face the following issues.

1. To enable both Orientation, use scrollview and horizontal scrollview. In this case only the vertical scrollbar is visible in the viewport and the horizontal scrollbar is available at the bottom of the content. We need to scroll to the end to see it. But I could see apps like Gmail, chrome in Android where both the scrollbars are visible in the viewport. How is this possible?
2. When applying scale to the contents, the contents are scaled and clipped inside the scrollview. It requires content resizing. When resizing, the pivot value of the contents are changed and pinch to zoom is not applied at the required touch pointers. But many android apps do this flawlessly.

Can anyone suggest or provide me a clue to achieve the above two?

Solution with Xamarin Android will be better. However, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Item 1 and 2 are difficult to answer without seeing your code.

But

I've implemented a zoomable and scrollable Table with Fixed headers (see https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout might give you some hints on how I overcame similar problems)

For scrollbars I extended a FrameLayout for mine, this is what implements the scrollbars as the top level parent ViewGroup, thus the scrollbars are always on the bottom and right of the outside edge and stay on the screen.
This was done by setting `setWillNotDraw(false);` in the ViewGroup and by implementing `computeHorizontalScrollRange` and `computeHorizontalScrollOffset` methods (as well as the vertical ones)

For Zooming I measure the children ViewGroups (The sub table parts) by overriding their `onMeasure` to `int measureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);`

Therefore the children ViewGroups are sized to be as big as they want to be and not clipped to the parents size, thus when you scale the view it has something that is normally offscreen to draw when a scale factor is applied.

**Update:**

Forgot to say that I only scale the child views by overriding `drawChild` method in the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hope this information can help me. Let me check and try these things.